HTTPHandler: Using lambdas to server specific paths
If you want all the code in a buildable format from the last 10 or so posts. You can find it here:
The PathMatcher object allows you to register paths with named sections of the path. But there are other vaiables available in the reuest. I want to make all the variables available to the lambda in a logic way.
So I have a wrapper class that Implements the PyntHttp interface and uses the PathMatcher to check if a request has a handler. If it does then we combine the header parameters query parameters and path match parameters into the variables() object to be used by the lambda:
HTTPHandler.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_NISSEHTTP_HTTP_HANDLER_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_NISSEHTTP_HTTP_HANDLER_H

#include "NisseHTTPConfig.h"
#include "PyntHTTP.h"
#include "PathMatcher.h"
#include "Util.h"
#include <string_view>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP
{

class HeaderRequest;

class HTTPHandler: public PyntHTTP
{
    using HTTPAction = std::function<void(Request& request, Response& response)>;

    PathMatcher             pathMatcher;
    std::vector<HTTPAction> actions;
    public:
        virtual void       processRequest(Request& request, Response& response);

        void addPath(std::string const& path, HTTPAction&& action);
    private:
        std::string normalize(std::string_view path);

        void addHeaders(RequestVariables& var, HeaderRequest const& headers);
        void addQueryParam(RequestVariables& var, std::string_view query);
        void addPathMatch(RequestVariables& var, Match const& matches);
};

}

#endif

HTTPHandler.cpp
#include "HTTPHandler.h"
#include "Request.h"
#include "Response.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP;

std::string HTTPHandler::normalize(std::string_view path)
{
    return std::string(path);
}

void HTTPHandler::processRequest(Request& request, Response& response)
{
    std::string path = normalize(request.getUrl().pathname());

    if (!pathMatcher.findMatch(path, request, response)) {
        response.setStatus(404);
    }
}

void HTTPHandler::addHeaders(RequestVariables& var, HeaderRequest const& headers)
{
    for (auto const& head: headers) {
        var[head.first] = head.second.back();
    }
}

void HTTPHandler::addQueryParam(RequestVariables& var, std::string_view query)
{
    // Add URL paramets to the variables object.
    if (query.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Remove the first ? or &
    query.remove_prefix(1);

    std::smatch     queryParamMatch;
    std::regex      queryParamExpr{"([^=]*)=([^&]*)&"};
    std::string     queryStr(query);
    queryStr += "&";

    while (std::regex_search(queryStr, queryParamMatch, queryParamExpr))
    {
        var[queryParamMatch[1].str()] = queryParamMatch[2].str();
        queryStr = queryParamMatch.suffix().str();
    }
}

void HTTPHandler::addPathMatch(RequestVariables& var, Match const& matches)
{
    for (auto const& match: matches) {
        var[match.first] = match.second;
    }
}

void HTTPHandler::addPath(std::string const& path, HTTPAction&& action)
{
    actions.emplace_back(std::move(action));

    pathMatcher.addPath(path, [&, actionId = actions.size() - 1](Match const& matches, Request& request, Response& response)
    {
        // Get the variable object
        RequestVariables&   var     = request.variables();

        addHeaders(var, request.headers());
        addQueryParam(var,  request.getUrl().query());
        addPathMatch(var, matches);

        actions[actionId](request, response);
    });
}

Hello World
We can now simplify the Hello World handler to:
    // Processes HTTP connection on port.
    ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::HTTPHandler   http;
    http.addPath("/HW-Length{Who}.html", [](ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::Request& request, ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::Response& response)
    {
        std::string     who  = request.variables()["Who"];
        std::string     page = R"(
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>Nisse server 1.1</title></head>
<body>Hello world: )" + who + R"(</body>
</html>
)";

        ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::HeaderResponse   header;
        response.addHeaders(header, page.size()) << page;
    });
    http.addPath("/HW-Chunked{Who}.html", [](ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::Request& request, ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::Response& response)
    {
        ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::HeaderResponse   header;
        response.addHeaders(header, ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP::Encoding::Chunked) << R"(
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
<head><title>Nisse server 1.1</title></head>
<body>Hello world: )" << request.variables()["Who"] << R"(</body>
</html>
)";
    });

